# search results based on categories or custom fields

Tags: php

---

So I have the below spitting out by post types; how could I edit to add custom field data to also populate? And or just categories?

```
 $categories = array(
        'post' => 'Articles',
        'mobile-experience' => 'Mobile',
        'staff-profiles' => 'Staff Profiles',
        'events' => 'Events',
        'page' => 'Page Content',);
```

It seems like the most standard feature for wordpress; a simple search results by categories -- and it's taking forever to implement; I have tried dozens of plugins and have gotten post types and a few other filters working, but not by category -- I'll forfeit custom fields, but I need to figure out category. I don't want to alter the search functionality of using keywords; but instead just populate each time it's found under category to appear within that category in the search results page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much of a help this will be, but this is a (probably overly convoluted) snippet of code I wrote a few years ago for a shortcode to display posts by category. If nothing else it may at least put you on the right track.

```
    $featured_posts = get_posts(
                            array(
                                'category' => $atts['cat'],
                                'posts_per_page' => -1
                            )
                        );
```